# Error: implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class

Tags: ios, objective-c

This my coding for the error part from my app

```
  - (id)initWithData:(NSData *)data <--------  
       options:(NSUInteger)options
         error:(NSError **)error
{
return [self
    initWithData:data
         content:XMLDocument
         options:options
           error:error
```

but on the first line it comes up with this 'Category is implementing a method which will also be implemented by its primary class'. so what does that mean and how do i fix it.

Comment: the error message is already very clear to me

Answer (score 2):

Category in obj-c is supposed to add some methods to base class. Not replace existing functionality.
You can't declare there methods with the same signature as already exist.

If you want to override the existing method (initWithData:...), you should use inheritance, you don't need category. If not - change method name, let it be for instance:

```
- (id)initWithXmlData:(NSData *)data options:(NSUInteger)options error:(NSError **)error
```